# Odoo database doesn't load after port change

Tags: database, port, odoo

The first thing i did in my odoo was created two databases, later i want to remove the port ip:8069 from the url so i do:

```
Go to terminal open rc.local file. rc.local file reside in etc folder.

sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
Paste this command on rc.local file and save


iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8069

Reboot Ubuntu, to see effect

sudo reboot
```

the result is that i can acces without put the port in the URL, but it send me to the page to create a database, not to the selection.
I think i must configure something in the databases created but i don't know what.

Can anyone help me?
thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1):

To change the port of an Openerp server, you have to make the change in config.py file. Which is located at

your-openerp-server/**openerp/tools/config.py**

and change the port in the below  **my_default**  attribute

group.add_option("--xmlrpc-port", dest="xmlrpc_port", **my_default=8069,**
                         help="specify the TCP port for the XML-RPC protocol", type="int")
and restart the server.